# How can an optocoupler detect the zero cross point in an AC wave?

Tags: opto-isolator, triac

I am having some trouble using Triacs in order to dim a light bulb operating at 220V AC, I am a student at school and I don't have any background about using Triacs or Diacs or so, so I seeked the internet for circuits which uses a microcontroller in order to control the Triac to control the speed of an AC fan or brightness of a light bulb.
[image]
So I got this circuit which I understand it all except there is a part I didn't understand in the circuit so that's why I am asking here for help.
[image]
So my question is concerned about this IC the MCT2e which I think is an optocoupler, how can this IC detect the zero crossing in the AC wave ? Although the input in this IC is rectified using a bridge rectifier ?
And also what is this IC properties ? Can any general purpose optocoupler be used or there is special specs. For it ? in short I want to know the principle of how this part of the circuit works in order to detect the zero crossing point in the AC wave.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Playing around with this circuit could kill you if you don't understand the dangers. Since you "don't have any background" I am not inclined to nudge you along that path. Take the time to learn the fundamentals before trying something like this; your great-grandchildren will thank you.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I appreciate you but I meant I don't have backgrounds in using Triac but I made a lot of digital AC switching using relays and I know the dangers I face quite well specially because my country uses 220V.

Comment: OK, what does it mean to you when you say that the input to the optocoupler is **rectified**? What does that signal look like? You ask about the "properties" of the optocoupler but have you tried to search for the datasheet of an MCT2E?

Comment: it could skip half the pulses in rectified dc to sync with the ac zc

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I mean that it is rectified from an AC voltage to DC voltage so the input to the IC is DC, and unfortunately I don't know how is the signal gonna look like and yes I read about the MCT2E but unfortunately I didn't understand anything in the datasheet rather than some simple things like forward voltage and current so I don't know If any optocoupler can do the job or no
.

Comment: No, the rectifier **does not** produce a dc voltage. If you don't know what the output of the rectifier will look like then you really have no business working with these lethal voltages.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson what I know is that the  rectifier diodes cut off the negative side of the AC wave and in a case of a full bridge rectifier the output of it can be around 300v bumpy DC and that's why there is a limiting current resistors  before the rectifier to not burning the optocoupler with this high voltage, but I all in all I am just in year 10 but I love electronics and trying to learn electrical engineering because I want to be one...and that is why I am here to learn from people who are electrical engineers :) and believe me I take all care .. I should take the risk in order to learn

Comment: Sorry, but you shouldn't risk your life while learning. Do you have a source of a lower ac voltage, isolated from the mains, that you can use for experiments? Maybe a 12V transformer?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson see I really thank you for your care about me but unfortunately what I do is not experiments but they are already done home made PCBs that is working at the moment perfectly using Relays so all what I thought of is to add a Triac beside these relays in order to control brightness of a light bulb or a fan speed.thats it

Comment: It doesn't detect the zero cross so much as it just detects when there is enough voltage to light the LED in the optocoupler. Try not to use DC to when referring to unipolar voltages or currents. There is an old guy at work here who does that and its infuriating because you never know if he is referring to the unipolar signal itself, or the constant DC component of the unipolar signal.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thank you so much I think this is a good answer for my question can you please post your comment as an answer but please put in your answer some simple graphical explanation for me to understand better .. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rectifier 'rectifies' ('puts right' or 'corrects') the negative halves of the AC cycle to make the voltage always positive, but doesn't make it smooth. It still goes down to zero at the end of each half cycle.

Here's the result of an [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html) simulation of your circuit:-

[image]

The blue trace is the 220V AC mains (divided by 20 to make the other traces more visible). Green is the rectifier output voltage, and red is the outocoupler output (ZVC).

The LED in the optocoupler shines light on the [phototransistor](https://instrumentationtools.com/phototransistor-working-principle/), which then draws current proportional to the LED current. As the rectified voltage drops close to zero the LED gets less current, so the transistor draws less current and the voltage at pin 2 (ZVC) rises. This tells the Arduino that the mains cycle is close to the zero crossing point.

Optocouplers are used to safely send signals between circuits which operate on different voltages. This is called [galvanic isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_isolation) because there is no direct electrical connection between the input and output. In this circuit the rectified voltage is still at mains potential so optocouplers are required to isolate the mains from the Arduino, allowing it to be connected to other equipment and handled without getting an electric shock.

The MCT2e is a standard optocoupler (similar to 4N25 etc.) with a minimum current transfer ratio (CTR) of 20%. Any optocoupler with similar specs should work fine. If you use an optocoupler with much higher CTR then the zero crossing pulse will be a bit wider due to its greater sensitivity.